# arrival rate in single server with general service time distribution.

Tags: queueing-theory

> Customers arrive at a single-server station with Poisson rate $\lambda$. A customer enters the bank if the server is available; otherwise, the customer leaves. The service times of successive customers are independent and have a common distribution $G$ and mean $\mu$. What is the rate at which the customer enters the system?

I am unable to figure out the answer. I assume that renewal reward process is to be applied here with regeneration happening at every service completion. Could anyone please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've never done one of these problems, but it would seem that the sum of two poisson random variables is another poisson variable. E.g $X= X_{1} + X_{2}$ with mean $ \lambda =  \lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} $. It seems idealized but they enter the computer when with rate $ \lambda + \mu$

Comment: answer was give as λ/(1+λμ)  . this is logic I could assume to arrive at the answer given .  since arrival happens after each service completion (as customer who enters when server is busy leaves the system), inter-arrival for an accepted customer would be service time μ + 1/λ (exponential arrival has memoryless property), therefore arrival rate is  λ/(1+λμ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question it is implicitly assumed that the system operates in the steady state.
For the steady state to exist the system's load (denote it by  $\rho$) must be less than one i.e.  $\rho=\lambda \mu<1$.

The system you are asking about, when operating in the steady state, follows the cycle
$empty \rightarrow busy \rightarrow empty \rightarrow busy \rightarrow ...$.
Thus the proportion of time that the system is empty is 
$$
{(mean \,\, empty \,\, time) \over (mean \,\, empty \,\, time) + (mean \,\, busy \,\, time)}= {{1 \over \lambda} \over {1 \over \lambda} + \mu}.
$$

Thus the arrival rate of customers which find the system empty is $\lambda \times {{1 \over \lambda} \over {1 \over \lambda} + \mu}$.

p.s. The latter conclusion uses the PASTA property of the Poisson process. So in general it is not valid.

p.p.s. in Kendall's notation, you are asking about the $M/G/1/0$ queueing system. In any classic queueing theory book, there are many results on this queue.